# Why can't I type from 20 to 23 , but can type below 19 and it works fine ( input type - time )

Tags: javascript, html, input, time

```html
<input type="time" />
```

On example above, you can see, when I type 19 - it replaces it to 07 `pm`, and it is correct, when I type 20, it converts it to 02 (and `pm/am` doesn't matter), is there any way to make it also works for range 20-23, when I type 20, it should convert it to 08 `pm`

Comment: In the snippet it doesn't convert anything, when I type 19 or 20 or 23. It just shows e.g. "23:00".

Comment: it does convert to 08 for me in FF..

Comment: Depends on the locale, not the browser.

Comment: @VLAZ can I preset some format which I want ?

Comment: seems like works differently on each locale

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#time_value_format

Answer (score 0):

**This is the expected behavior for a time input on most browsers now.** Typing in anything over 12 on a 12-hour clock will be interpreted as such. So "14" will return "02" and "19" will return "07".

The time input works according to the OS settings. For you and me, that's 12-hour. For much of the world, it's 24-hour. That's just how the input works, and you can read more about this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time).

Regarding a solution, I don't think this is something you can force change (i.e. against a user's default preferences) without using a different input type. Instead of time, you'd have to use text or numeric inputs and configure them to behave as a 24-hour clock.